# Azure Cloud Service Web Role not starting - Unhandled exception - Unable to find Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-roles

I have an ASP.NET Web API hosted in a cloud service web role.  I have added a WebRole class extending RoleEntryPoint which is attempting to retrieve an IoC castle Windsor container which has dependencies setup in the StartUp.cs of my web API.  I want to then retrieve a logger instance I have registered and use that in my WebRole.

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    private ICancellationTokenSourceProvider _cancellationTokenSourceProvider;
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        try
        {
            var container = IoC.GetContainer();
             _cancellationTokenSourceProvider = container.Resolve<ICancellationTokenSourceProvider>();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return base.OnStart();
    }
```

---

However when I try to deploy this to the cloud service I get the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: Unable to find assembly 'Castle.Windsor,
> Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc'. at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
> at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo
> assemblyInfo, String name) at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String
> objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA,
> Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader
> objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo,
> SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable) at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped
> record) at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run() at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
> handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
> isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
> serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
> isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream
> stm) at System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[] blob) at
> System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[] blob) ' [2020-06-19T16:48:01Z]
> Last exit time: [2020/06/19, 16:48:05.617]. Last exit code: 0.

I have tried to find the cause and solution to this extensively.

- I have tried to add binding redirects to the missing assembly in
  MyApi.dll.config and ensuring it is set to copy always.
- I have also
  ensured the assembly has **Copy Local** set to true as well.

However, I still get this error every time and the web role keeps restarting trying to recover from this exception.

Comment: Give some suggestions, you can try whether it can be resolved, looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Has your problem been solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Read your problem description carefully, I think the problem should be in the problem of loading assembly such as `MyApi.dll`.

First, because of the limitations of Azure's cloud environment, it may not be possible to load some third-party assemblies. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260747/dllimport-does-not-work-on-azure-app-service-net-3-1/61268680#61268680).

After the Azure Cloud Services service is created, you can get a virtual machine, and you can log in using `RDP`. So I suggest that you create your application first, do not contain the code that references the third-party `.dll` , to ensure the successful deployment. Then log in with `RDP` method to the virtual machine, open `cmd`, use the `regsvr32 xxx.dll` related command to register the third-party `.dll` file in the registry, and then redeploy your complete project now. Check if the problem is solved.