# Azure and C++ DLL files

Tags: c#, c++, azure, azure-web-app-service, dllimport

I have a web app on Azure. It uses .NET Core 3.1. I use two C++ DLL files as dependencies in the app. The first DLL depends or uses  the second DLL. When I run the project in Visual Studio locally, there is no issue. When I deploy the app to Azure, it complains only from the second DLL, and it says "unable to load dll or one of its dependencies". As I said the first DLL use the second DLL in its codes by using " [DllImport(@"..\Folder\Second.dll")] ". What do I need to do or add in web app? Why it is working locally anf not on Azure? Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Probably you didn't publish the DLL to Azure... but since you didn't provide any diagnostic info, we can't help you.

Comment: Following lan Kemp's suggestion, first copy your dll file to the specified path. (Through kudu, open the scm website).

Answer (score 1):

1. First make sure that your `.dll` does not need to be registered in the registry on your local computer. Then you can copy and paste your `.dll` file directly into the `scm` website for testing. If it can be successful, then it can be supported.

   In this way, we only need to add the following code to the `.csproj file`, and include your `.dll` file when publishing.

   [The specified files are included in the release.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67181866/azure-functions-dont-publish-appsettings-prod-json-file/67206074#67206074)
2. If your .dll needs to be registered in the computer registry, then I can tell you clearly that azure web app is not supported because it is a sandbox environment.

   ***But you can publish your application through azure container webapp or virtual machine.***

   ## Related Post

   [DLLImport does not work on Azure App Service Net. 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260747/dllimport-does-not-work-on-azure-app-service-net-3-1/61268680#61268680)